# Search Keywords within mulitiple XMls and echo tho file ID when Keyword is matched via PHP

Tags: php, regex, xml, search, keyword

I want to discuss about a programme , which i need to create within PHP.Before i start to code, i need some advices from you guys.

Description:

There are 100's of XML files are stored on the Linux server and within the XML there is **description** node about the XML file and every XML file has a **Unique ID**

so what i need to do is , want to create web page where user can put some keyword in the search bar and then this keywords needs to be searched within these 100's of XML and if the Keywords are matched within these XMl's then we needs to show the ID of all the XML where these keywords are matched!

Before i start this i wants to have some views and concerns and then what will the best way to design this Project.

any small algorithm will be really helpful! any kind of thought on it will be really appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a DB for this.

Comment: This All XML's are already created with other script on the linux machine and i need to just search within these XML's and then echo the file ID , if the Keyowrd is matched

Comment: It is going to be inefficient this way and a hassle in the future.

Comment: yes! that what my concern but there is no other way to get the entry of XML to database becasue ,

XMl system is already being used and i get to work now with existing XMLs and when user needs search something through Webpage then just echo the File ID.

Comment: You could parse the XML and write it to a DB if you can't write it one the first pass (where it is being generated).

Answer (score 0):

flow logic: get the search term, open each xml file with simple_xml_load_file(); in a loop that loops through the directory, if the tag matches "description", save the filename in an array, then output that array.

Comment: thanks @Ehab Eldeeb , for your advice! and on of anotehr concern is this XML numbers will be increased every day and it will soon in 1000's of XML.
any server load problem or any problem with PHP?

Comment: it depends on the server's capabilities i.e. processor speed ... other than that, it should be smooth